# What are some good resources to understand the code for 3D Gaussian Splatting?

Tags: deep-learning, papers, pytorch

I am looking for some good resources like videos or blogs (or other githubs!) that go through the code of Gaussian Splatting and explain the major components and how they are working. Haven't found anyone explaining the code on their official github, even though it's gaussian splatting is being talked about so much!